# Salesforce API Opportunities split System.DmlException: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Unable to create an opportunity team member

Tags: api, opportunity, exception, opportunity-split

I am new to salesforce.I have enabled oppotunity split with check box checked for team enabled.
While i run some code or through salesforce api i am getting the following error

System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 400 with id @#$%#$$#%$%@$#; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Unable to create an opportunity team member for new opportunity split user.: [SplitOwnerId]

```
List<Opportunity> theOppList = new List<Opportunity>([Select Id, Software_Platform__c, AccountId, Name FROM Opportunity where Software_Platform__c=null and AccountId!=null]);

System.debug(theOppList);
Map<Id,Opportunity> theAccOppMap = new Map<id,Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity theOpp:theOppList){

    theAccOppMap.put(theOpp.AccountId,theOpp);
}
```

Comment: have you masked the Id or is salesforce giving you the same exact Id as error, if salesforce is giving you this as Id then it would be good to see what you are adding to the update list before you update

Comment: that is an id that is masked , owner of that opportunity is not the one who is logged in.I have updated the code for the same